# How does Direct branching or leaf nodes (dbl) function in Tjfast algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I read an algorithm about Twig Pattern Matching  as TJfast algorithm.
there is a function as dbl(n) ,the parameter n is a node and this function returns direct Branching or leaf Nodes but I can not understand that , the name of article is " From region encoding to extended dewey: On efficient processing of XML twig pattern matching " there is an example but is vague for me.
Base on definition in the article :

> dbl(v) (for direct branching or
>   leaf node) returns the set of all branching nodes b and leaf nodes f in the twig
>   rooted at v such that there is no branching nodes along the path from v to b or
>   f, excluding v, b or f.

example :

[image]

```
dbl(a)={b,c}
dbl(c)={f,g}
```

I can not understand why dbl(c)={f,g} ??

Comment: Can you please link the paper you're reading? [The one I'm reading here](https://dl.comp.nus.edu.sg/jspui/bitstream/1900.100/1516/1/upload.pdf) does not appear to have a definition of `dbl`, and it also doesn't seem to have the tree structure that is in your question.

Comment: you can see the article here :
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.111.5197
and 
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1083618

Answer (score 0):

`dbl (directBranchingOrLeafNodes)` only contains branching nodes and leaf nodes. Among those nodes, it only contains ones in which there is *no* intermediate branching node between them and the root.

It's surprisingly hard to find the definition for a branching node, but it appears to be a node that has more than one child. `d` and `e` are not branching nodes, because they only have one child. Therefore, they cannot be part of `dbl(c)`.

Then, the path from `c` to `f` has no branching nodes, so `f` is in `dbl(c)`. Likewise, the path from `c` to `g` has no branching nodes, so `g` is in `dbl(c)`.
So we have:

```
dbl(c) = {f,g}
```

I'm guessing they probably use `dbl` to represent subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

dbl(a) = {b,c}, because b is a leaf node and c is a branching node and both of them are descendants of a. In addition, note that there are no other branching node or leaf node which are a descendant of a and an ancestor of b( or c).

dbl(c) = {f,g}, because f and g are leaf nodes and both of them are descendants of c. In addition, note that there are no other branching node or leaf node which are a descendant of c and an ancestor of f(g).